# Error C language

Tags: c, turbo-c

This code cannot convert `char*` to `char**`. I don't know what it means.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

shift( char *s[] , int k )
{
  int i,j;
  char temp[50];

  for( i = 0 ; i < k ; i++ )
    temp[i]=*s[i] ;

  for( j = 0 ; j < strlen(*s) ; j++ )
    {
      *s[j] = *s[k] ;
      k++ ;
    }

  strcpy(*s,temp);

}

main()
{
  int i,j=0,k;
  char s[30];

  printf("please enter first name ");
  gets(s);

  scanf("%d",&k);
  shift( &s , k);
  puts(s);

  getch();
}
```

The program is supposed to:

> read string S1 and index ‘K’, then call your own function that rotates the string around
>   the entered index.  The output of your program should be as follows:
>
> ```
> Enter your string:  AB3CD55RTYU
> Enter the index of the element that rotates the string around: 4
>
> The entered string:  AB3CD55RTYU
> Enter the element that rotates the string around:  D
>
> The rotated string is :  D55RTYUAB3C
> ```

Comment: where is the definition of the `shift`

Comment: You are confusing `char s[]` with `char* s[]`, these two mean very different things...

Comment: Cannot convert char (*)[30] to char **

Comment: @Nim i did that to change the variables in the main function

Comment: The *type* of `&s` is not `char* []` (which means an *array of pointers*), rather a pointer-to-pointer (`char**`), typically an array decays to a pointer to the first element of the array, and you are passing the address of that pointer to your function. So your function definition is not correct.

Comment: so what if i want to make the function change in the main value

Comment: @Nim look if i removed the * and code will be like 'shift(char s[],int k)
{
int i,j;
char temp[50];
for(i=0;i<k;i++)
temp[i]=s[i];
for(j=0;j<strlen(s);j++){
s[j]=s[k];
k++;}
strcpy(s,temp);
} ' 
it will return only the first nums without rotating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&s` means `char (*)[30]`(pointer to array of char[30]) not `char *[]` (array of pointer to char)

For example, It modified as follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

void shift(char s[],int k){
    int i, len;
    char temp[50];

    for(i=0;i<k;i++)
        temp[i]=s[i];
    temp[i] = '\0';
    len = strlen(s);
    for(i=0;k<len;i++)
        s[i]=s[k++];
    strcpy(&s[i],temp);
}

int main(){
    int k;
    char s[30];
    printf("please enter first name ");
    gets(s);
    scanf("%d", &k);
    shift(s , k);
    puts(s);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this works but strcpy(&s[i],temp); why you put & and [i] in the cpy code i always uses it with [i] and don't know why the and there

@bluepixy

Comment: @AhmedDarkness `strcpy` requires address (`char *`) to indicate a destination. the address of copy from `temp` to it is the address of `s[i]` in this case.

Comment: it always need a destination ? because i always use it without & ..
and s[i] i didn't get it still 
in usual if i want to cpy between 2 strings i would write it
strcpy(s,temp)

Comment: @AhmedDarkness `strcpy` will require address. However, you can use the `s + i` instead of `&s[i]` in this case.

Comment: well thats good why i can use the s+i :D
sorry i really in need to understand this @bluepixy

Comment: @AhmedDarkness `s` represents the first address of the array.
`i` represents the pointer movement amount of the relative position from it.
So `s+i` will be the same meaning as the address of the i-th element of the array.

Comment: So if i put s+1 it will start cpying after the first element 
also i want ask how the value returned to the main function ? @bluepixy

Comment: @AhmedDarkness *so if i wrote s+1 the compiler will start copy after the first element ?* yes. I think there is no need to return value contents of the array you are working in the `shift` function from is the same as that in the main. (I have misunderstood the intent of the question?)

Comment: yes i mean i learned in my course that functions don't store the value in the orginal place so we use pointers to connect it with the main function and let it edit it ,, here we used no pointers so how it edits s in the main function ? 
thats my question  @bluepixy

Comment: @AhmedDarkness Be passed to another function array Since passing a pointer in general, it means that you are working with the original rather than what you edit another array that has been copied in the function. And then manipulate it and copy it to secure a new area in the function, or the structure as long as you expect it to be copied if. There is a need to return to the main copy in that case. But they will say that it is after all redundant operation, with the exception of if you need to preserve the original.

Comment: you mean iam working with the original one already without any uses of pointers right ?
and why that didn't happen always we have to use pointeR :D
sorry iam asking you as a professor of mine :D

Comment: @AhmedDarkness Array passed to another function as mentioned already is used as a pointer. Even if you did not think you is not ever used the pointer actually if you were using a pointer. It is clear even look at the code you've written. I might have misunderstood the question because it is not a native. Please think of using a pointer that's inevitable in the C language anyway.

Comment: @AhmedDarkness It is not possible to use the `strcpy` If prohibit the use of the pointer if. Take a look at the prototype declaration of `strcpy`.

Comment: the problem with me is why i didn't use s only .. you explained this because i want to start from i  // secondly you explained by that its the same like original or something like that .. 
very special thanks to you, you helped me very much

Comment: @AhmedDarkness I wrote a copy version for you. It might help to something.

Answer (score 0):

example using a structure(Copy is performed). However, this is waste of resources.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

typedef struct word {
    char str[30];
} Word;

Word shift(Word word, int k){
    Word temp;
    int i = 0, j;

    for(j=k;word.str[j]!='\0';++j)
        temp.str[i++]=word.str[j];
    for(j=0;j<k;++j)
        temp.str[i++]=word.str[j];
    temp.str[i] = '\0';
    return temp;
}

int main(){
    int k;
    Word w;
    printf("please enter first name ");
    gets(w.str);
    scanf("%d", &k);
    w=shift(w , k);
    puts(w.str);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
shift(char* s[],int k); //shift expects char**; remember s[] is actually a pointer

main()
{
  char s[30]; // when you declare it like this s is a pointer.
  ...
  shift(s , k); 
}
```

You should change the shift function signature to `shift(char* s,int k);` since you don't really need pointer to pointer. You just need to pass the beginning of the array.